# Computing the sky coordinates using astropy

Tags: observational-astronomy, coordinate, gaia, astropy

I need your help with an error I have been receiving while trying to obtain the sky coordinates using astropy module in python.

The code looks like the following,

```
c = coord.SkyCoord(ra = u.Quantity(gaia_data["ra"] * u.deg),
               dec = u.Quantity(gaia_data["dec"] * u.deg),
               distance = u.Quantity(gaia_data["distance"] * u.pc),
               pm_ra_cosdec = u.Quantity(gaia_data["pmra"] * u.mas/u.year),
               pm_dec = u.Quantity(gaia_data["pmdec"] * u.mas/u.year),
               radial_velocity = u.Quantity(gaia_data["rv"] * u.km/u.s))
```

I have read the queried data from Gaia DR3 into a pandas dataframe which is why I am converting the individual columns to quantity to ensure correctness while calculating the coordinates. The thing that surprises me the most is that the code works perfectly fine when I run it on a smaller dataset from Gaia DR3 (about 40k objects), the error pops up when I try doing it for the actual dataset (about 2.1M stars).

The error message looks like the following,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e9a930de875e> in <module>
      4                    pm_ra_cosdec = u.Quantity(gaia_data["pmra"] * u.mas/u.year),
      5                    pm_dec = u.Quantity(gaia_data["pmdec"] * u.mas/u.year),
----> 6                    radial_velocity = u.Quantity(gaia_data["rv"] * u.km/u.s))

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/coordinates/sky_coordinate.py in __init__(self, copy, *args, **kwargs)
    329             # Finally make the internal coordinate object.
    330             frame_kwargs.update(components)
--> 331             self._sky_coord_frame = frame_cls(copy=copy, **frame_kwargs)
    332 
    333             if not self._sky_coord_frame.has_data:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/coordinates/baseframe.py in __init__(self, copy, representation_type, differential_type, *args, **kwargs)
    581                     if not current_diff_unit.is_equivalent(current_repr_unit / u.s):
    582                         raise ValueError(
--> 583                             "Differential data units are not compatible with"
    584                             "time-derivative of representation data units")
    585             self._data = representation_data.with_differentials(

ValueError: Differential data units are not compatible withtime-derivative of representation data units
```

I do not understand the error message and I did not find any relevant source explaining what this means and how do I get rid of it?

Did anyone encounter this before? What is the solution?

Comment: What version of astropy are you using? I see that the latest version has a much more [helpful error message](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/6fda4d5dc40e94e8944c2d23ba5a7004be330479/astropy/coordinates/baseframe.py#L568) which may make it easier to diagnose. Unfortunately I see that you're running Python 3.6 while the latest versions of astropy claim to require >=3.8.